# Can you disable dependencies expanded in the charts/ directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Using helm I know you can disable a dependency in **requirements.yaml** using a **condition**.

However, I have a dependency copied into the **charts/** directory and expanded because I need more control over it.

Is there is any way to conditionally include this dependency given that it's not included via **requirements.yaml** but rather through expanding in the charts/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to [helm dependency docs](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_dependency.md):

> Starting from **2.2.0**, repository can be defined as the path to the directory of the dependency charts stored locally. The path should start with a prefix of "file://". For example,
>
> ```
> # requirements.yaml
> dependencies:
> - name: nginx
>  version: "1.2.3"
>  repository: "file://../dependency_chart/nginx"
> ```
>
> If the dependency chart is retrieved locally, it is not required to have the repository added to helm by "helm repo add". Version matching is also supported for this case.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Then adding a condition works just fine!